# do decltype needs an expression involving complete type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code, which tries to determine existence of a nested typedef.

```
  #include<type_traits>
  struct foo;// incomplete type
  template<class T> 
  struct seq
  {
       using value_type = T;
  };
  struct no_type{};
  template<class T>
  struct check_type : std::true_type{};
  template<> 
  struct check_type<no_type> :std::false_type{};
  template<class T> 
  struct has_value_type
  {
    template<class U>
    static auto check(U const&)-> typename U:: value_type;
     static auto check(...)->no_type;  
    static bool const value = check_type<decltype(check(std::declval<T>()))>::value;
    using type = has_value_type;
  };
  int main()
  {
      char c[has_value_type<seq<foo>>::value?1:-1];
      (void)c;
  }
```

Now invoking `has_value_type<seq>::value` causes compilation error as invalid use of incomplete type `seq<foo>::value_type`. 
does `decltype` needs a complete type in the expression? If not, how can I remove the error? I am using gcc 4.7 for compilation.

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: error from gcc 'invalid use of incomplete type 'seq<foo>::value_type{aka struct foo}' forward declaration of 'seq<foo>::value_type{aka struct foo}'

Comment: Are you providing a definition for `foo` at a later point, or not at all? Can you please update your code so that it is a complete example (one that we can copy/paste/compile)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is valid C++11, which defines that a toplevel function call that appears as a decltype operand does not introduce a temporary even when the call is a prvalue.

This rule specifically was added to make code as yours valid and to prevent instantiations of the return type  (if it is a class template specialization) otherwise needed to determine the access restrictions of a destructor.

Answer (score 2):

`decltype` requires a valid expression, and you certainly can have a valid expression that involves incomplete types. The problem in your case however is

```
template<class U>
auto check(U const&) -> typename U::value_type;
```

which has return type `foo` when `U` is `seq<foo>`. You can't return an incomplete type by value, so you end up with an ill-formed expression. You can use a return type of e.g. `void_<typename U::value_type>` (with `template<typename T> struct void_ {};`) and your test appears to work.

Comment: this answer is incorrect as far as c++11 is concerned. i will post an explanation.